# Post JSON to ASP.NET MVC 4 action from JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an app that uses ASP.NET MVC 4. In some ways, I feel like I'm learning everything from scratch :). I'm told its worth it.

I need to post some JSON to an Action in my controller. My action looks like the following:

```
[Authorize]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RemoveItem(string itemID)
    {
      // Do stuff...
      return Json(new { Status = 1, Message="Success" });
    }
}
```

My JQuery code looks like the following:

```
function removeItem(id) {
  var json = { "itemID": id };
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/myController/removeItem",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: json,
    dataType: "json",
    success: removeItemCompleted,
    error: removeItemFailed
  });
}

function removeItemCompleted(results) {
}

function removeItemFailed(request, status, error) {
}
```

In Fiddler, I notice a 500 error is returned.  The TITLE field in the response says: "Invalid JSON primitive: itemID".

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: What does your `json` variable's value look like?

Comment: If that's all you're passing there's really no need to create the variable. Your method expects a string named `itemID` so you should be doing something like: `data: { itemID: id }` No quotes around `itemID`

Comment: @MarcusRecck without the double quotes it's not valid JSON.

Comment: I'd like to learn the JSON approach. I actually need to pass more data. I was trying to trim it down for the sake of example. All of my data is key/value pairs though and no nested arrays or anything like that. That's why I want to use JSON.

Comment: @BillJones - Understood-- but in this case, there is no need to pass anything other than itemId. If your Action expected an object, then you could send a json stringified object over the wire.

Comment: Holy cow. I wish I didn't have to scour the internet looking for this post every time I start a new MVC project that needs to post JSON to an action method. Does it seem bad to anyone else that you have to copy/paste this stuff into every project?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Be sure to send JSON:

```
data: json,
```

should be

```
data: JSON.stringify(json),
```

IE7 and below needs a shim: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

NOTE: Dave A's answer is also correct, but doesn't directly answer your issue. I +1'ed it.

Comment: thanx @Joe, haters be everywhere

Answer (score 6):

you don't seem to need JSON here. Ideally, the id param would be passed in your URI:

```
 url: "/myController/removeItem/"+id
```

That is probably why your Action can't be identified. It requires a parameter.

**Followup:** Critics who point out that data passed is a string and therefor cannot be passed as an id are incorrect. I *should* have pointed out that the action method should be re-written to accept `string id`.

Comment: Dave please check his controllers action. He mentioned it as string and not as integer. By appending id to url it cannot be done AFAIK

Comment: ahhh yes, I was a little sloppy. great excuse for hating ;) It really should be passed as an id. String or not.

Comment: as a follow up @Karthik you're completely wrong that an id can't be a string.

Comment: i'm sorry if i'm wrong with my comment. Can it be passed if a string is passed instead of an int ?. I thought if it was string then only strings can be passed to it. Thanks for the follow up

Comment: Also am not your hater Dave. I find many of your posts on SO to be useful. My bad i couldn't much when commenting out

Answer (score 4):

```
          function removeItem(id) {
  var json = { "itemID": id };
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/myController/removeItem",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(json),
    dataType: "json",
    success: removeItemCompleted,
    error: removeItemFailed
  });
}

function removeItemCompleted(results) {
}

function removeItemFailed(request, status, error) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
$('#delete').click(function () {
        var APIURL = "/api/products";
        var id = $('#SearchText').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            url: APIURL + '/' + id,
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Employee deleted');
            }
        });
    });
```